# Can coverity tool scan python codebase for SCA and security issues?

Tags: python, command, coverity

Can coverity be used for scanning python code base. If yes, then what inputs to be given in cov-build command? It would be good to have whole sequence of cov commands for scanning python code.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a dummy project that looks like:

```
src/
  file.py
  file2.py
  tests/
    test1.py
    test2.py
3rdparty/
  skip.py
setup.py
```

And you want to analyze everything except the `3rdparty` folder, you can execute the following commands:

```
cov-configure --python

cov-build --dir foo \
          --no-command \
          --fs-capture-search ./ \
          --fs-capture-search-exclude-regex ./3rdparty

cov-analyze --dir foo \
            --all \
            --aggressiveness-level high

cov-format-errors --dir foo \
                  --html-output results

cov-commit-defects --dir foo \
                   --host coverity.mycompany.com \
                   --stream MYSTREAM \
                   --auth-key-file mycoverity.key
```

**Explanation:**

`cov-configure --python`

Inform Coverity that you will be scanning Python code

`cov-build`

Inform Coverity to build your code. Since Python is not compiled but interpreted, does not need to be built (`--no-command`) but Coverity still needs to know where to get the sources from (`--fs-capture-search`). You can add more than one `--fs-capture-search` or `--fs-capture-search-exclude-regex` arguments to suit your needs. The "built" sources will be placed into the `foo` directory (`--dir foo`).

`cov-analyze`

Perform the actual code analysis on the "built" sources placed at  `foo`. There's a ton of switches you can pass here but I think that for Python those would be enough.

`cov-format-errors`

Generate a useful HTML report inside a new `results` folder. Other output formats are supported, not just HTML.

`cov-commit-defects`

Commit the scan results into your Coverity Connect central server at the specified stream. For the commit to work you have to identify yourself using a Coverity key file (you download this key from the Coverity server Web UI), and this file needs to be readonly for the user (i.e. `chmod 400 mycoverity.key`)

**NOTE:** All the above works fine against my company's internal Coverity server (i.e. paid product). For the free for open source version of Coverity, things might be different (have not tested it). For the later case I'd look at some of the open source projects: https://github.com/search?q=--fs-capture-search&type=Code